# Why does the Empire/First Order always spend their time looking for the Rebellion/Resistance?

Tags: star-wars

In the Star Wars movies, I always get the impression that the Sith/Empire/First Order spend a reasonable amount of their time looking for the Rebellion/Resistance (please say if i'm wrong), if so, then why do they find it so difficult? There are clearly charted maps of the galaxy which show areas under Rebellion/Resistance control, so why can't they just fly over and try and annihilate them?

Comment: The Rebellion don't hold territory and nor do the Resistance. They have secret bases.

Comment: In fact, in most galaxies far far away, evil forces did just that, annihilated the good guys swiftly and efficiently. The only galaxy where this did not happen is the one we get to see in the movies, precisely because it makes for such a compelling story.

Comment: That being said, the only base which we really get to see in the movies being properly annihilated as part of the story is the Echo base on Hoth, shouldn't this happen more as it is a large part of the storyline?

Comment: because that's how the game is played: https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/star-wars-rebellion/ ;)

Comment: @CHEESE Why cheese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no "areas under Rebellion/Resistance control."  They don't control anyone except themselves; they live through a series of secret bases.  They have friends, as mentioned in the Last Jedi, but these people are no more under their jurisdiction than the Empire themselves.

That said, the Empire/First Order does seem to be pretty good at finding these bases--the galaxy is big, there are a lot of planets from which to choose, and they seem to find a different base in every movie.

Comment: It could well be that the Empire/Order has a lot of separate searches going on (e.g. the probe droid that found the base on Hoth was suggested to be part of a large group that was sent out to scan for rebels), we just tend to only see the ones that succeed. The only weird part is that the successful searches often include a ship with a very high ranking officer on board rather than just being some random ship in the area.